# Errors when using bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile

Tags: python, scripting

I'm running the following simple python code with no issues as far as the .blend file with the object I'm modifying is already open.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['obj']
obj = C.scene.objects.active
obj.select = True
obj.rigid_body.type = 'PASSIVE'
```

However, if I add a line at the beginning of my code to open the file,

```
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=task_path+ str(x) +".blend")
```

it opens the file and then I get an AttributeError after obj.rigid_body.type (object has no attribute 'type'). I've already spent several days trying different things. Could anyone help me to understand this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the file you're loading doesn't have rigid body physics enabled for the object?

Comment: In the physics tab the object should have rigid body enabled. Or you can add `bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()` to your script to initialize it.

Comment: @gtzkw Thank you. That makes sense. I had that line (bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()) in my code before, but that gave me another error I wasn't able to understand: RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add.poll() failed, context i incorrect